# Non-zero continuous function $f(x)$ such that $\int_0^1x^k (1-x)^{n-k} f(x)dx=0$ for every $k=0,1,...,n$ and $n$ is a non-negative integer.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Does there exists a non-zero continuous function $f$ such that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^k (1-x)^{n-k} f(x)dx=0$ for every $k=0,1,2,...,n$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer.

EDIT: The problem is related to Weierstrass approximation using Bernstein approximation of certain function. As you can see the term $x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$ comes from Bernstein polynomials. I want my integral to vanish for non-zero $f$.

Also, the result should hold for every $n$ and for every $k$ running from $0$ to $n$. For example, for $n=2$, we shall have three integrals corresponding to $k=0,1,2$. In this way, it should hold for any $n$.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Do you mean everywhere nonzero or not identically 0?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I edited the question. Please let me know if it needs further improvement.

Comment: @VanLatimer Not identically non zero.

Comment: You say that $n$ is fixed. You can easily construct lots of such $f$ for $n=1$. Just look at polynomials such that $\int_0^{1}f(x)dx=0=\int_0^{1} xf(x)dx$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, $n$ is fixed in the sense we have to run $k$ from $0$ to $n$. But then $n$ is also allowed to vary. For example, for $n=2$, we shall have three integrals corresponding to $k=0,1,2$. In this way, it should hold for any $n$.

Comment: The set $$ V_n = \left\{ f \in L^2([0,1]) : \int_{0}^{1} x^k(1-x)^{n-k}f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0 \text{ for every } k = 0, \cdots, n \right\} $$ is the orthogonal complement of the set of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$, and in particular, is not only non-empty but in fact an infinite-dimensional subspace of $L^{2}([0,1])$. One can find an explicit orthogonal basis of $V_n$, for instance, using the [*shifted Legendre polynomials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials), which are of course continuous.

Comment: @SangchulLee Great!!! Can we exhibit at least one such $f$ explicitly?

Comment: You may as well restrict to $k=0$ and for all $n\ge 0$. Clearly, $(1-x)^{n-k}$ is a polynomial in $x$ and thus, if the integral is zero for all $n\ge 0$ and $k=0$, it is zero for all $n\ge k\ge 0$ also.

Comment: Choose $f(x) = \tilde{P}_{n+r}(x)$, where $\tilde{P}_{\bullet}$ are the shifted Legendre polynomials and $r \geq 1$. Then it satisfies $\int_{0}^{1} x^k(1-x)^{n-k}f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$ for all $k = 0, \cdots, n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee The problem is that your choice for $f$ depends upon $n$ which I don't need for my original problem. I want $f$ independent of $n$. My integral is of the form $\int_0^1 g(x)f(x)dx$ where $n$ and $k$ comes by approximating $g$ using Bernstein polynomials. I should be able to plug in $f$ in this integral to get 0!

Comment: Ah, I thought that you are asking examples of $f$ for each given $n$. If the condition should hold for all $n$, then $f$ must be identically zero, by the standard approximation technique, i.e., choose a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ that approximate $f$ in $C([0,1])$ to see that $$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1} f(x)p_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{\text{(by assumption)}}= 0. $$ This is enough to conclude $f \equiv 0$. The conclusion continues to hold (modulo measure-zero modification) for larger class of functions.

Comment: @Yes, right! But what if my  $f$ is bounded and measurable not necessarily continuous. Would it  still be identically zero?

Comment: @ersh a continuous function epsilon close to f in L1 would have by the triangle inequality and holders inequality would have integral epsilon against all your polynomials. This could not happen unless f was 0 almost everywhere. That’s a very rough thought though, not sure it pans out.

Comment: If $f$ is $L^1$, then one can show that its Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi x} \, \mathrm{d}x$ is identically zero, which is enough to show that $f$ is zero a.e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s the sketch: Since we require this for every $k$ and $n$, it amounts to saying that the integral of f against any $x^k (1-x)^j$ is zero. These are closed under multiplication, so their span is an algebra. By Stone-Weierstrass, find linear combinations $l_n$ of them approaching $f$ uniformly. By the assumption in the problem, $\int l_n f$ is 0 for all $n$, so taking a limit we conclude $f^2$ integrates to 0. It however is positive, so it is identically 0. Therefore $f$ is identically 0.

Comment: @ Van Latimer, It really seems such $f$ must be zero. I am reading your proof.

Comment: Right, sorry I didn’t state that explicitly till the end.

Comment: Well,, because $n$ is non- negative, if $g_1 := x^k(1-x)^{n-k}, \; g_2 := x^m(1-x)^{n-m}$ and $k + m > n $, then $g_1 g_2=x^{k+m}(1-x)^{n-k-m}$ is not in Span $\{ x^k(1-x)^{n-k} : n \geq 0 , k=0,1, \dots n \}$ ??